# Prevent prompting to treat theme to be loaded as safe for future sessions

Tags: emacs, themes

I am using the following theme in my emacs `init.el`

```
(require 'color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow)
(color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow-day)
```

However, everytime my Emacs starts, it asks me "`Loading a theme can run Lips Code. Really load?`" After that it asks "`Treat this theme as safe for future sessions?`"

What do I need to do so that its accepted as a Yes overtime. I am sure this can be customised in Emacs, but I am still quite new to the editor and lisp in general.

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved as follows..

```
;;; Treat all themes as safe
(setq custom-safe-themes t)
```

Note: Please put this before the theme is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to load the theme with the optional NO-CONFIRM switch, like this:

```
(load-theme 'color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow-day t nil)
```

the description for load-theme says this:

```
load-theme is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘custom.el’.

(load-theme THEME &optional NO-CONFIRM NO-ENABLE)

Load Custom theme named THEME from its file.
The theme file is named THEME-theme.el, in one of the directories
specified by ‘custom-theme-load-path’.

If the theme is not considered safe by ‘custom-safe-themes’,
prompt the user for confirmation before loading it.  But if
optional arg NO-CONFIRM is non-nil, load the theme without
prompting.

Normally, this function also enables THEME.  If optional arg
NO-ENABLE is non-nil, load the theme but don’t enable it, unless
the theme was already enabled.

This function is normally called through Customize when setting
‘custom-enabled-themes’.  If used directly in your init file, it
should be called with a non-nil NO-CONFIRM argument, or after
‘custom-safe-themes’ has been loaded.

Return t if THEME was successfully loaded, nil otherwise.
```